# Internal server error 500 on wordpress on Apache server

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, server, lamp

I'm getting a 500 internal server error from time to time on a VPS server running Ubuntu 15.04 and Apache (installed like the perfect server here: https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/perfect-server-ubuntu-15.04-with-apache-php-myqsl-pureftpd-bind-postfix-doveot-and-ispconfig/)

The server has 5 Wordpress installs and the sites have no traffic to speak of as they're being deployed. The VPS is from digital ocean with the following specs: 1GBMemory, 1 CoreProcessor, 30GBSSD Disk, 2TBTransfer.

Can the resources be maxed out -- or is there a different explanation?

This is the error log from /var/log/apache2: http://pastebin.com/zVjJh8fP

Thanks in advance,

Kind reagards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has to do with APC failing to allocate enough memory. Try lowering shm_size. But if possible increasing your memory would be a good idea.